# Confusing start times vs. time windows in Network Analyst

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, time

This is the snippet of my ArcPy script that deals with route-making:

```
TechRoute = arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer(inNetworkDataset, RouteName, "Minutes",
                                    "FIND_BEST_ORDER", "PRESERVE_FIRST", "USE_TIMEWINDOWS")
field_mapping = "TimeWindowStart TWStart1 #;TimeWindowEnd TWEnd1 #"
arcpy.na.AddLocations(RouteName, "Stops", TechLayer, field_mapping, "1000 Meters", "VisitOrder")
outputLayerFile = os.path.join(workingDir, "opt{}".format(RouteName))
```

Note that I'm not assigning any value for the `start_date_time` parameter for `na.MakeRouteLayer`. I decided to leave it out since I want the route to start at 8am, and in [the Esri help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00480000000n000000), it says

> The default value for this parameter is 8:00 AM.

Unfortunately, it's not starting anywhere CLOSE to 8am. (And also not starting on today's date, but I am not interested in the date so I don't care.)

[image]

As best I can figure it's using the time windows, which (for this particular route) all start at 8am and end at 6pm, and *working backwards*. This isn't what I expected and also seems a bit silly (wouldn't most users want to start at the beginning of a time window?). For another technician's route without any appointment windows, it's starting at midnight instead of 8am. (Again, not what I would expect!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head-scratching, I called Esri Technical Support and got a fuller explanation of the issue.

Without having a defined start time, `arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer` essentially starts *whenever it wants*, as long as that start time still respects the time windows. Having the time windows overrides the default start time. This makes some sense; if your earliest window starts at 10am, for example, an 8am start time would be pointless.

Therefore, explicitly defining a start time solves the problem and makes Network Analyst work the way I was hoping. Appropriate code:

```
TechRoute = arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer(inNetworkDataset, RouteName, "Minutes", "FIND_BEST_ORDER",
                                    "PRESERVE_FIRST", "USE_TIMEWINDOWS", "#", "#", "#", "#",
                                    "#", "#", "10/31/2014 8:00 AM")
```